# what are the difference between "create feature vectors then train" with "direct train" in image classification

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am researching about image classification. And I don't understand the difference between creating a feature vector through an available model https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_101/feature_vector/1. Then training again. Compared with direct training by that model

Answer (score 0):

This concept is related to transfer learning , where you can create features some times called as bottle neck features through the already trained and available model and then you can create a new model on top of them and train to fine tune to your problem. 
In the other case you are training your network from scratch completely to solve your task.